# How to limit the cpu usage of slurm?

Tags: slurm

So I am running a slurm job across 2 laptops (2 nodes), and I notice both laptop gets insanely laggy, to the point that the mouse could not even move. When I uses htop I saw the job was using 4 cores in 100% usage. I know for sure that the job does not take up that many cpu usage. How do I make slurm so that it uses only the required amount of cpu power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm does not put any additional load onto the CPUs of your node. Besides what it needs for slurmd/slurmstepd, which is not much. If your job has access to four cores and you only use one, the others will be idle.

Maybe your program does something unexpected?